# Change label background color...first red, then yellow on second click

Tags: ios, xcode, background

I cannot find anything relating to it. I'm a beginner but I'm assuming that I need a NSArray to change the colors.

Anyway, I have a button and when you click the button once it changes a label background to GREEN. How do I make it so the first click it changes the label background to green...and then the second click it changes the background to YELLOW

```
- (IBAction)studentOne:(id)sender {
_studentOne.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
_studentOne.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
_studentOne.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
_studentOne.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
_studentOne.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


}
```

That would be my sequence.

Would it be something involving

```
NSArray *colorArray;
colorArray = [NSArray array with objects:
```

I tried this because I thought it may be like changing text color on a button click

```
- (IBAction)studentOne:(id)sender {
NSArray *colorArray;
colorArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:

@"_studentOne.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor]",
@"_studentOne.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor]",
@"_studentOne.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]",
@"_studentOne.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor]",
@"_studentOne.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor]",
              nil];


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right about the array, a little off on the syntax.  Something like this will work:

```
- (IBAction)studentOne:(id)sender {

    static NSArray *colors;
    if (!colors) colors = @[[UIColor redColor], [UIColor greenColor], [UIColor yellowColor]];

    UIColor *currentColor = myLabel.backgroundColor;
    NSInteger index = [colors indexOfObject:currentColor];
    index = (index == NSNotFound || index == colors.count-1)? 0 : index+1;

    self.myLabel.backgroundColor = colors[index];
}
```